# How to run tests in JavascriptCore?

Tags: javascript, react-native, testing, javascriptcore

I'm developing a js library that should be consumable by react-native projects as well. The javascript engine used by react-native is JavaScriptCore, which has its differences compared to node or engines used in browsers. There are quite a few things missing, or behaving differently: URL, Buffer, Blob.

It would be nice to catch these kind of issues without causing regressions for library consumers.

Is there a test runner which supports such scenario?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I have the same problem. Which testing framework did you use.

Comment: @KaizerSozay haven't found a proper solution, we have deprioritized it for now.

Answer (score 0):

The usual go-to test framework used with react-native is Jest,

https://jestjs.io/

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react-native.html

Check if it will suit your requirements.

Comment: I'm aware of jest, do you know of a preset which enables you to use it with JavascriptCore?